# Implement the From trait for generic enum

Tags: generics, rust, enums

The following code example gives an error:

```
enum NonGeneric {
    A(i32),
    // other variants with same type
}

impl From<NonGeneric> for i32 {
    fn from(value: NonGeneric) -> Self {
        match value {
            NonGeneric::A(a) => a,
        }
    }
}

enum Generic<T> {
    A(T),
}

impl<T> From<Generic<T>> for T {
    fn from(value: Generic<T>) -> Self {
        match value {
            Generic::A(a) => a,
        }
    }
}
```

the error:

```
error[E0210]: type parameter `T` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (`Generic<T>`)
  --> src/lib.rs:18:6
   |
18 | impl<T> From<Generic<T>> for T {
   |      ^ type parameter `T` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (`Generic<T>`)
   |
   = note: implementing a foreign trait is only possible if at least one of the types for which it is implemented is local, and no uncovered type parameters appear before that first local type
   = note: in this case, 'before' refers to the following order: `impl<..> ForeignTrait<T1, ..., Tn> for T0`, where `T0` is the first and `Tn` is the last

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0210`.
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=enum%20NonGeneric%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20A%28i32%29%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20From%3CNonGeneric%3E%20for%20i32%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20from%28value%3A%20NonGeneric%29%20-%3E%20Self%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20match%20value%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20NonGeneric%3A%3AA%28a%29%20%3D%3E%20a%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aenum%20Generic%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20A%28T%29%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CT%3E%20From%3CGeneric%3CT%3E%3E%20for%20T%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20from%28value%3A%20Generic%3CT%3E%29%20-%3E%20Self%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20match%20value%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Generic%3A%3AA%28a%29%20%3D%3E%20a%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20a%20%3D%20NonGeneric%3A%3AA%284%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20v%3A%20i32%20%3D%20a.into%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20assert_eq%21%28v%2C%204%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20let%20g%20%3D%20Generic%3A%3AA%284%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%7D)

I do not really understand the error. The two implementations do not differ that much, it is only that the type of the data is not a specific type. I would assume it does not make any difference. I also tried with `impl<T, G: Generic<T>>` or creating a trait for the enum and using that as generic argument, without success.

What is the proper way of implementing the From trait for a generic enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not allowed according to the [orphan rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/implementations.html#orphan-rules).

> Given `impl<P1..=Pn> Trait<T1..=Tn> for T0`, an impl is valid only if at least one of the following is true:
> [..]
>
> - No [uncovered type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/glossary.html#uncovered-type) parameters `P1..=Pn` may appear in `T0..Ti` (excluding `Ti`)

where `P1` == `T0` == `T` from your attempted implementation, it's uncovered and it's the first time `T` appears according to the rules given in the reference.

The fact that that's the error is also repeated in the notes of the *full* error message:

> = note: implementing a foreign trait is only possible if at least one of the types for which it is implemented is local, and no uncovered type parameters appear before that first local type
> = note: in this case, 'before' refers to the following order: `impl<..> ForeignTrait<T1, ..., Tn> for T0`, where `T0` is the first and `Tn` is the last

It's a bit confusing but the type that the trait is implemented on `Self` is the first considered parameter and it too cannot be an [uncovered type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/glossary.html#uncovered-type) parameter.

Comment: Thank you. Than it seems I don not have other choice but to implement it for every type I would like to use specifically. Am I right?