# Make custom string type PartialEq with "any" str

Tags: rust

I have a custom string structure (`CustomString`), which uses a (platform dependent) data type and encoding to represent a string in rust.

I've implemented the `Display` trait for this struct, to allow display the value and converting it into a `String`.

I now want to leverage this feature to make it comparibale with any other "String" (not only `&str`, `String`, but anything, that can be converted into a `&str`).

One direction is not a problem, as I can

```rust
impl<S> PartialEq<S> for CustomString where S: AsRef<str>
```

to make everything, that can be represented as `&str` comparible with my `CustomString`. This allows writing `custom_str == str`, but not `str == custom_str`.

I've tried

```rust
impl<S> PartialEq<CustomString> for S where S: AsRef<str>
```

but this does not compile with the following error:

```
error[E0210]: type parameter `S` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (`CustomString`)
```

My question now is, how can I express (if at all), that anything, that is representable as `&str` can be compared with my custom string?

I've created a [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cb6395ffb7f101d39fd41718874973a3) that demonstrates the problem.

I've also looked at the suggested [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75842511/implement-the-from-trait-for-generic-enum) but that doesn't really aswer my question.

My question is not, why it's not possible to do `impl<S> PartialEq<CustomString> for S`, but whether it is possible to express, that anything which can be represented as `&str` is comparible to my custom string.

If this is not possible, this would imply, that any user of my crate, that uses another string representation (e.g. from another 3rd-party crate), must wrap *both* types to be able to implement specific `PartialEq` traits for them. Right?

Comment: You can't write a blanket implementation for a trait you don't own.

Comment: Why wouldn’t it be possible in your case to implement “ impl<S> PartialEq<S> for CustomString where S: AsRef<str>” instead of “ impl<S> PartialEq<CustomString> for S where S: AsRef<str>”?

Comment: @Goldenprime if you open the playground link they did, but Rust's traits / operators don't support reflexivity, so it only works one way (`custom == str`) and the other (`str == custom`) gets a compile error which is... not super nice.

Comment: "This is not allowed according to the orphan rules." – i.e. no you cannot. "anything, that is representable as `&str`" necessarily includes foreign types for which you can't implement a foreign trait.